# line-in no sound while using Jack and Guitarix Pi4

Tags: audio, pi-4

I am trying to get guitarix with jack running on a Pi4.
The USB Audio device is working properly for line out e.g. watching youtube.

As soon as I start jack and guitarix, the audio stops playing.
Now I've set up Jack and guitarix like this:
[image]

Alsa Mixer is showing:
[image]

But there is no sound input when clicking the Tuner Tab in Guitarix.
I tried connecting a guitar, a microphone but no sound.

What could I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found the mistake.

The microphone and guitar adapter I was using a designed with a 3 ring 2.5 jack.
This sort is often used for smartphones e.g.
I've got an adaptor for the microfon with 2 ring 2.5. jack shown below too and now it is working
The Sabrent USB Audio Adapter only acceppts the 2 ring jack.

[image]

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.